# How to pass struct params in remix ide?

Tags: solidity, remix, struct, abiencoderv2

I have this smart contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract TestStruct {

      struct User {
        string name;
        uint256 age;
     }

    mapping (bytes32 => User) users;

    function addUsers (User [] memory _users) public {

        for (uint i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) {

           bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(_users[i].name));
           users[hash] = _users[i];

        }
    }

    function getUser (string memory username) public view returns (User memory) {

        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(username));

        return users[hash];
    }
}
```

I want to test it using remix IDE,
But I didn't find the write way to pass the array of struct in remix UI

I try this [image]

And I got this error:

```
transact to TestStruct.addUsers errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function takes an array of structures as an argument:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Declare the value directly and replace the **brackets** with **square brackets**

[["maro",20]]

more detail: [HERE](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/udapp.html#:%7E:text=To%20pass%20a%20tuple%20in,top%20of%20the%20solidity%20file.)